# Ruby on Rails Issue with trailing zeros in decimal number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal, bigdecimal

We are currently developing a Webapp with Ruby on Rails where we do some optimization calculations. Initially, we import the data from a CSV-File. These files contain a record every 15 minutes throughout a whole year. So there like 35k records with timestamp and value. One record looks like this:

01.01.2018 00:15;34.82

Unfortounately, we've come across some strange behaviour. If the CSV was formatted with trailing zeros, the results differ from the calculations without the trailing zeros.

01.01.2018 00:15;34.82**00**

In RoR we do format the values as floats, but I feel like the small imprecision of float datatypes should not have any impact on this.

Any ideas, what's going on? I was digging deep in our code and could not find what was causing this issue. Changing the datatype from float to BigDecimal didn't help either.

Comment: Computers don't look at numbers the way we human do. Maybe [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2t9Wej0hyI&feature=youtu.be) can give you a better understanding of what's going on. It's about money and how integers and floats works.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm aware of this and I did try to work with BigDecimal instead of floats, but the issue persisted. Also, it is not about the decimals itself, i'm not having any issues with the calculations, as long as there are no trailing zeros.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're changing the timestamp to decimal, where you can just convert `01.01.2018 00:15;34.82` to DateTime like this `'01.01.2018 00:15;34.82'.to_datetime` and can perform any calculation required to calculate time difference etc

Comment: What do you mean with "the results differ from the calculations with the railing zeros"? how do they differ? do they differ with any value? '34.82'.to_f == '34.8200'.to_f => true. Can't you just remove trailing zeros before parsing the value to a float?

Comment: Are you talking about just the 34.8200? You could use `truncate`:
`34.8200.truncate(2) #=> 34.82`